# Linking errors for Qt and cvv when building OpenCV in Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, build, cmake

I am trying to build **OpenCV** according to [these instructions](https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/). After generating with **CMake** I opened **OpenCV.sln** in the build folder, switched to Release mode and built **ALL_BUILD** successfully. But when I try to build the **INSTALL** option under CMake, I get errors like this:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl cvv::qtutil::Signal::metaObject(void)const " 
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cvv::qtutil::ZoomableImage::updateConversionResult(class cv::Mat const &,enum cvv::qtutil::ImageConversionResult)const " 
...
```

I am installing OpenCV 4.2 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 19. How can I solve this problem?

Here is an image of the error messages in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Did you perform the steps in Step 9: "**Setting Up the Flags for the installation of OpenCV**"? Also, perhaps [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8977) thread may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I performed Step 9 exactly as it said. That thread suggests turning off **opencv_world**. Is this a good idea? I might need it later. If I have to, should I remove the `build` folder and make it from scratch?

Comment: I built successfully with the opencv_world enabled

Comment: Yes, but it also suggests setting a CMake variable `BUILD_opencv_cvv` to `OFF`, which seems to be more relevant to your issue. I'm not sure if you need that package? And yes, removing the `build` folder and starting over from scratch could be helpful if you've made several CMake-related changes and you think the CMake cache may be corrupted or incorrect.

Comment: there is a solution [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/210338/build-error-when-activating-both-cvv-and-world/?answer=210340#post-id-210340) that says turn off `opencv_world`. At the end it says: **later, you'll have to link against single module libs, like -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc, etc**. What does this linking mean exactly?

Comment: If you turn off opencv_world, those modules which have problem, won't get built but the other ones, will be built and you can use them, but if opencv_world is ON, in this case, you can't use none of the modules (because it tries to put all of them in world and fails). I don't know what your problem is exactly but I had such troubles too when I was trying to build opencv along with lots of other libraries too (like protobuf, itk, ...). Check the interacting libraries in Cmake and remove those who are not needed by you.

Comment: My problem seems to be a conflict between **Qt** and **cvv**. When I use visual studio I add **opencv_world.lib** to `properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`. What would I have to do if I remove **opencv_world** entirely?

Comment: Did you try the suggested? Setting `BUILD_opencv_world` to `OFF`?

Comment: @squareskittles, For now, I just set `BUILD_opencv_cvv` to `OFF` to see if it works. It is still building the `INSTALL`. If this doesn't work I will turn off `BUILD_opencv_world` as well.

Comment: @squareskittles It worked with `BUILD_opencv_cvv` turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer:*

The GitHub issue described [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8977) references similar errors to those you have posted. While the suggested "solution" seems more like a work-around, it may help resolve the issue. First, try building without the [`cvv`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cvv/doc/cvv.html) module (an interactive GUI component of OpenCV), by running CMake with the `BUILD_opencv_cvv` variable set to `OFF`:

```
cmake -DBUILD_opencv_cvv=OFF ...
```

You can also set the variable using the CMake GUI, by clicking the **Add Entry** button, and defining `BUILD_opencv_cvv` to `OFF`.

The GitHub issue further explains that if there are still undefined reference errors after making this change, you can also try setting `BUILD_opencv_world` to `OFF` as well.

```
cmake -DBUILD_opencv_cvv=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF ...
```

This may help get things building successfully, but it should be noted that these disabled modules will be left out of your build.