# LNK errors on building opencv contrib cvv module

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake

I am building opencv 4.3.0 in the windows-vs2015, using cmake3.17.3, with `WITH_QT` enabled. Here are errors messages related to `opencv_contrib` module `cvv` in the building process:

```
     Creating library C:/opencv/opencv-4.3.0-cbuild/lib/Release/opencv_world430.lib and object C:/opencv/opencv-4.3.0-cbuild/lib/Release/opencv_world430.exp
view_controller.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl cvv::gui::CallTab::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@CallTab@gui@cvv@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
image_call_tab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl cvv::gui::CallTab::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@CallTab@gui@cvv@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
view_controller.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl cvv::gui::CallTab::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@CallTab@gui@cvv@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
image_call_tab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl cvv::gui::CallTab::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@CallTab@gui@cvv@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
view_controller.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl cvv::gui::CallTab::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@CallTab@gui@cvv@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
image_call_tab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl cvv::gui::CallTab::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@CallTab@gui@cvv@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
view_controller.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject 

 .........

C:\opencv\opencv-4.3.0-cbuild\bin\Release\opencv_world430.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 226 unresolved externals
```

What is the problem with these errors? I googled online and found some similar posts (https://answers.opencv.org/question/210338/build-error-when-activating-both-cvv-and-world/; [Linking errors for Qt and cvv when building OpenCV in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753002/linking-errors-for-qt-and-cvv-when-building-opencv-in-windows-10)). It seems that `BUILD_opencv_world`, `WITH_QT` and `Build_opencv_cvv` cannot be activated simultaneously for building. Should I need to remove the `cvv` module from the opencv_contrib folder?

Comment: The [answers.opencv.org](https://answers.opencv.org/question/210338/build-error-when-activating-both-cvv-and-world/) answer pretty clearly explains what the problem is. Did you try the alternatives in the links you provided? Did they work? Do they not work for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to turn Build_opencv_cvv off and start building again, and will update my post regardless of success or not